# Understanding logical form of "Nobody in the calculus class is smarter than everybody in the discrete math class"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

I'm self studying `How to Prove` book and have been working out the
following problem in which I have to analyze it to logical form:

> Nobody in the calculus class is smarter than everybody in the discrete
>   math class

Now, this is how, I started solving it:

> ¬(Somebody in the calculus class is smarter than everybody in the
>   discrete math class) 
>   ¬(If x is in calculus class then x is smartert than everybody in the discrete maths class)

C(x) = x is in calculus class.
D(y) = y is in discrete class.
S(x,y) = x is smarter than y

```
¬∃x(C(x) -> ∀y( D(y) ∧ S(x,y)))
```

But this is the solution given in the Velleman's book:

¬∃x[C(x) ∧ ∀y(D(y) → S(x, y))]

I cannot understand how that answer is correct. Can someone explain
the thing I'm missing there ?

---

There is also a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373136/how-to-logically-analyze-the-statement-nobody-in-the-calculus-class-is-smarter) asked there but that doesn't discuss the Velleman's answer per se.

Comment: Think of $\forall x\in X \varphi(x)$ as standing for $\forall x (x\in X \rightarrow \varphi(x))$ and $\exists x\in X \psi(x)$ as standing for $\exists x (x\in X \wedge \psi(x))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer asserts that there does not exist anyone $x$, who, iF $x$ is in Calculus, then (all students y are both in Discrete math and x is smarter than them.)  This is clearly not what is conveyed in the original statement.

What we need, essentially, is "There does not exist someone $x$ who is  enrolled in Calculus AND such that, for all students y, if y is enrolled in Discrete math, then x is smarter than y. $$\lnot \exists x\Big(C(x) \land \forall y(D(x) \rightarrow S(x, y))\Big)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ denote the set of members of calculus class and let $D$
the set of members of discrete math class.

The following statements are equivalent (explore step by step) and the last one is the Velleman answer:

1) Nobody in the calculus class is smarter than everybody in the discrete
math class

2) For every person $x$ in $C$ there is a person $y$ in $D$ such
that $\neg S\left(x,y\right)$

3) $\forall x\in C\exists y\in D\left[\neg S\left(x,y\right)\right]$

4) $\forall x\left[x\in C\Rightarrow\exists y\left[y\in D\wedge\neg S\left(x,y\right)\right]\right]$

5) $\neg\exists x\neg\left[x\in C\Rightarrow\exists y\left[y\in D\wedge\neg S\left(x,y\right)\right]\right]$

6) $\neg\exists x\neg\left[x\notin C\vee\exists y\left[y\in D\wedge\neg S\left(x,y\right)\right]\right]$

7) $\neg\exists x\left[x\in C\wedge\neg\exists y\left[y\in D\wedge\neg S\left(x,y\right)\right]\right]$

8) $\neg\exists x\left[x\in C\wedge\forall y\left[y\notin D\vee S\left(x,y\right)\right]\right]$

9) $\neg\exists x\left[x\in C\wedge\forall y\left[y\in D\Rightarrow S\left(x,y\right)\right]\right]$

There is quite some redundancy here, but I hope this give you understanding about the correctness of the answer.