# Is my symbolic representation of "nobody loves everybody" correct?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose we want to represent "nobody loves everybody" and the universe of discourse is all people. Would a correct representation be:

$$\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{(\forall x)(\sim \!x\Rightarrow(\forall y)(y\Rightarrow (\sim\!x) \; \text{loves} \; y )) \; \; \; \text{(Universe is all People)}}$$

**Edit:** I made a second attempt

$$\sim\!\!(\forall x)(x\Rightarrow(\forall y)(y\Rightarrow x \; \text{loves} \; y )) \; \; \; \text{(Universe is all People)}$$

According to the answer key, the answer is

$$(\forall x)\!(\sim\!\!(\forall y)(x \; \text{loves} \; y))$$

Am I correct? If not then why?

Comment: You are using $x$ and $y$ as if they were propositions rather than elements of the universe of discourse, so your proposed answer is not a well-formed formula. E.g., $x$ and $y$ are meant to range over people: but $\mbox{sally}\Rightarrow ((\sim\mbox{joe}) \mathrel{\mbox{loves}} \mbox{sally})$ doesn't make any sense, even though we can get it from your second implication by substituting sally for $y$ and joe for $x$.

Comment: @RobArthan I made edits. How is my second attempt.

Comment: You are still using $x$ and $y$ as propositions ($x \Rightarrow \ldots$, $y \Rightarrow \ldots$).

Comment: Why is, "Some boys like clowns" the same as, "$(\exists x)(x \; \text{is boy} \; \land (\forall y)(y\Rightarrow x \; \text{likes} \; y))$"

Comment: @RobArthan See [the accepted answer to this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373136/how-to-logically-analyze-the-statement-nobody-in-the-calculus-class-is-smarter?rq=1)

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any bearing on the fact that your proposed answer is not a well-formed formula.

Comment: @RobArthan How do we improve my answer to make well-defined. I still don’t understand why my second answer is not well defined.

Comment: You are using $x$ and $y$ as if they were propositions. I can't really help you improve your answer other than to comment that you don't need any implications as the answer you have been given shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Edit:** I made a second attempt
>
> $$\sim\!\!(\forall x)(x\Rightarrow(\forall y)(y\Rightarrow x \operatorname{loves} y )) \; \; \; \text{(Universe is all People)}$$

Firstly, $x$ and $y$ as propositions do not make sense.   It would if you we using the proposition $x\in\mathcal U$, where $\mathcal U$ is some explicit domain or other restriction.  However, as you have an implicit domain of discourse, you do not need the implication.   So we shall drop them:

$$\sim\!\!(\forall x)(\forall y)(x \operatorname{loves} y ) \; \; \; \text{(Universe is all People)}$$

Secondly, *this* says "not everyone loves everyone", which is still not what you require, that is "not *some*one loves everyone."

Remember this: No-one is short for "Not Someone"; it is the claim *there does **not exist** an example of this*.

So we shall change that to an existential. We can also use the **duality of quantifies** to 'move' the negation inwards, once or twice.

$${\sim\!\!(\exists x)(\forall y)(x \operatorname{loves} y ) \; \; \; \text{(Universe is all People)}\\(\forall x)({\sim}\forall y)(x\operatorname{loves}y)\\(\forall x)(\exists y)\;{\sim}(x\operatorname{loves}y)}$$

Which says, "Everyone has someone they do not love."   Which is equivalent to "No-one loves everyone".

Answer (score 0):

Let $L(x,\,y)$ mean "$x$ loves $y$". Working with quantifiers over people, the statement is $\neg\exists x\forall y(L(x,\,y))$ or something equivalent. The cleanest notation may be $\forall x\exists y(\neg L(x,\,y))$.